# How can I create or manage user accounts on an Android 11 Oppo phone

Tags: multi-user, oppo

I have a new phone (Oppo A54 - 5G) and I like to [create a second user account](https://www.howtogeek.com/333484/how-to-set-up-multiple-user-profiles-on-android/).

The phone has Android 11 installed, and according to [change user - Android 11](https://youtu.be/yqBZaFfw_0U) tutorial, it should be possible to create/change user accounts in Android 11.

But on the Oppo phone, I don't see the user account buttons in the top bar, and I can not find in in the settings.

So I would like to know:

- is it possible to create and use multiple users on an Oppo Android 11 phone?
- if yes, that where can I find the settings menu to create users and switch to the new users?

Comment: Oppo phones don't use Android they use ColorOS. Mostly ColorOS is identical to Android, but there can be differences. So you should better use the manuals from Oppo: https://support.oppo.com/en/answer/?aid=neu12782

Comment: Hmm... my ColorOS version is 11.1, the oppo manual says, multi-user should be available since ColorOS 10, but I dont have the multi user option in my settings.

Is there anything I must do to enable the multi-user menu?

Comment: `The availability of Multi-user Mode depends on the phone model and ColorOS version.` This means that some models don't support multi-user mode.